# How would you turn a thermite reaction into an electrochemical cell?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

A [previous question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/173461/72973) asked about oxidation and reduction agents in the following reaction (not sure about the appropriate physical state of the oxides, solid or liquid, but shown here as liquid):

$$\ce{Fe2O3(l) + 2 Al(l) -> 2 Fe(l) + Al2O3(l)}$$

The false claim in a video was that because oxygen gets transferred, oxygen is the oxidation agent. We usually determine what gets reduced and what gets oxidized by looking at oxidation states. However, these are a fairly arbitrary construct.

Sometimes, it helps to show the reaction split into two components. Here is a naive way:

$$\ce{Fe2O3(l) -> 2 Fe(l) + 3/2 O2}$$
$$\ce{2 Al(l) + 3/2 O2 -> Al2O3(l)}$$

So aluminum gets oxidized, and iron oxide gets reduced. However, there is no elemental oxygen in the real reaction, so this is not a clean argument. In this scheme, you can see that we start with oxygen in an oxide, go to elemental oxygen, and then back to an oxide, so the oxygen is doing (net) nothing, which is confusing as well but helps to debunk the false claim in the video.

More useful would be to split this redox reaction into half reactions. Because you can "see" the electrons in the half reactions, it makes it clear that this is indeed a redox proces. To make it realistic, these would exclude water and elemental oxygen, so this would happen at high temperatures with molten salts and (depending on the temperature) either solid or liquid metal electrodes:

$$\ce{Fe2O3(l) + 6e- -> 2 Fe(s) + 3 O^2-(ms)}$$
$$\ce{2 Al(s) + 3 O^2-(ms) -> Al2O3(l) + 6 e-}$$

The phase designation (ms) is supposed to stand for a molten salt.

My question is how you would realize these two half reactions in an electrochemical cell. How would you build the electrodes (would they be solid or liquid), what would you use as salt bridge or semi-permeable membrane to connect the two ion-containing solutions so that ions can be transferred, and what would you use as solvent (some molten salt)?

I found analogous iron and aluminum chloride molten salt batteries e.g. in [this paper](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/42959/10800_2005_Article_BF01030182.pdf?sequence=1) (https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01030182), but nothing yet on an electrochemical cell based on the oxides.

Comment: As the thermite reaction is not elementary, there can be elementary oxygen. There could be similar E. diagrams for Al as [Ellingham diagrams for carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellingham_diagram)

Comment: @Poutnik I did not know about Ellingham diagrams. In this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260028609_Mechanism_for_thermite_reactions_of_aluminumiron-oxide_nanocomposites_based_on_residue_analysis) they have elementary reactions releasing dioxygen but find them unlikely because of a positive Gibbs energy of reaction even at high temperatures.

Comment: The chemical potential of oxygen changes between the oxides, so it is driving the reaction (with aluminum as accomplice). Those first reactions could be used as cells. The oxygen dianion looks brutally unstable. \[edit\] "However, there is no elemental oxygen in the real reaction, so this is not a clean argument." That's the point with half reactions, Hess's law and much of thermodynamics: additivity of individual steps.

Comment: @Karsten Hello Karsten. Your question is about *which* chemical materials to use as a cathode, anode, electrolyte, etc.; for this system?

Comment: @MetalStorm yes, and the temperature that makes it feasible